# TikZ scalebox without translation

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

Below are two TikZ pictures. In the second one, I've added a `\scalebox` to scale the nodes ABC and the distance between them. I want the A to remain in the same position, but unfortunately the coordinates are scaled with respect to origin.

How can I rescale that part of the figure without translating it?

[image]

MWE for the picture with a scalebox:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node at (0,0) {0,0};
\node at (4,4) {4,4};
\node at (0,4) {0,4};
\node at (4,0) {4,0};

\scalebox{0.67}{
    \node at (2,2) (A) {A};
    \node [right=of A] {B};
    \node [below=of A] {C};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

To be clear: I do want the distances between A, B and C to scale, I just don't want the entire scalebox to move towards origin. In my actual document, the contents of the scalebox are more complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `scope` with options `scale=0.67` and `transform shape` instead of the `\scalebox`. All numeric coordinates inside the scope will be scaled. But you can use an outside the `scope` defined named `coordinate` as "anchor" to position the node `A`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines](0,0)grid(4,4);
\node at (0,0) {0,0};
\node at (4,4) {4,4};
\node at (0,4) {0,4};
\node at (4,0) {4,0};
\coordinate (O) at (2,2);% coordinate for positioning node A
\begin{scope}[scale=0.67,transform shape]
    \node at (O) (A) {A};
    \node [right=of A] {B};
    \node [below=of A] {C};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]